# What is the difference between "apt-get install <package_name>/testing" and "apt-get install -t test <package_name>"

Tags: debian, apt

What is the difference between `apt-get install <package_name>/testing` and `apt-get install -t test <package_name>`? Both should specify target release(`stable`, `testing`, `unstable`, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
apt-get install <package_name>/testing
apt-get install -t test <package_name>
```

> The first will not attempt to upgrade any packages on your system, so if specific dependencies are not met, the install will fail.
>
> The second method will attempt to install/upgrade any dependencies. Of course, given the above example, 'apt-get' will ask you before proceeding.

Answer from [Debian wiki :AptPreferences](https://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences)

Answer (score 3):

Well , this questions tickles my mind from yesterday that i first read your post.

Typically, these two versions of the apt-get install are the same according to apt-get man pages.

Practically, these two versions are indeed the same when you try to install one or more packages with a known name.

But if you try to install multiple packages using wildcards then i could observe some differences.

This command fails:

```
apt-get install -s mate*/testing
```

While this command works fine:

```
apt-get install -s -t testing mate*
```

It seems that the mate*/testing search from all packages containing mate and tries to install all thos packages from testing repo. If some packages are not  available in testing repo then you get an error and apt-get fails.

On the other hand the -t testing mate* , selects mate* packages available in testing repo only. 
It doesn't try to search and install mate* packages that are not available in testing repo and thus it doesn't fail.

You can give it a try if you want to above commands, using the -s (simulate) option which allows you to see all the apt-get messages in your terminal as would appear in a real install (but nothing is really installed).

PS : There is a also a obvious and minor difference between two versions:
Working with "/release" version you can combine (if you ever want so) various packages from various /releases, while with "-t release" version you set globally the release to be applied to all packages that will follow apt-get install.